data write and read on c++ won't working while on debug mode, but it will working while on release mode
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


struct Mahasiswa {
    int pk{};
    std::string NIM{};
    std::string Name{};
    std::string Jurusan{};
};


void write_data(std::fstream &data, int posisi, Mahasiswa &input_mahasiswa) {
    data.seekp((posisi-1)*sizeof(Mahasiswa), std::ios::beg);
    data.write(reinterpret_cast < char*> (&input_mahasiswa), sizeof(Mahasiswa));
}

Mahasiswa read_data(std::fstream &data, int posisi) {
    Mahasiswa input_mahasiswa;
    data.seekg((posisi - 1) * sizeof(Mahasiswa), std::ios::beg);
    data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&input_mahasiswa), sizeof(Mahasiswa));
    return input_mahasiswa;
}


int get_datasize(std::fstream& data) {
    int start;
    int end;
    data.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    start = data.tellg();
    data.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    end = data.tellg();
    return (end - start) / sizeof (Mahasiswa);
}

void display_data(std::fstream &data) {
    Mahasiswa show_data;
    int ukuran_data{ get_datasize(data) };

    std::cout << "PK \t" << "NIM \t" << "NAMA \t" << "JURUSAN \n";
    for (int i{ 1 }; i <= ukuran_data; i++) {
        show_data = read_data(data, i);
        std::cout << "PK :" << show_data.pk << "\t";
        std::cout << "NIM :" << show_data.NIM << "\t";
        std::cout << "NAMA :" << show_data.Name << "\t";
        std::cout << "JURUSAN :" << show_data.Jurusan << "\n";
    }
}

void check_data(std::fstream &data) {
    if (data.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Data ditemukan \n";
}
    else {
        data.close();
        std::cout << "Data tidak ditemukan \n";
        data.open("data.bin", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    }
}


int main()
{

    std::fstream data;
    data.open("data.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    check_data(data);

    
    int ukuran_data{ get_datasize(data) };
    std::cout << "Ukuran data: " << ukuran_data << std::endl;


    Mahasiswa input_mahasiswa;
    Mahasiswa last_mahasiswa;

    if (ukuran_data == 0) {
        input_mahasiswa.pk = 1;
    }
    else {
        last_mahasiswa = read_data(data, ukuran_data); // I guess this part is not working cause the read_data()

        std::cout << "PK: " << last_mahasiswa.pk << std::endl;
        input_mahasiswa.pk = last_mahasiswa.pk + 1;
    }
   
    std::cout << "NIM = ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input_mahasiswa.NIM);

    std::cout << "Name = ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input_mahasiswa.Name);

    std::cout << "Jurusan = ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input_mahasiswa.Jurusan);

    write_data(data, ukuran_data + 1, input_mahasiswa);


    display_data(data);

    return 0;
}

I think the write and read for data is not working because the program is stop while on the read_data(), especially on the debug mode. But why the code working without any problem while on the release mode? Can anyone explain why?

Reading and writing binary data is not something you should try yourself. It is just too fragile (mismatching compilers/compiler settings and/or different computers may all lead to your code to fail). What you are trying to do is called "binary serialization" (look it up) and is notoriously hard to get right. In all cases use a library (protobuf/flatbuffers) or just serialze to and from .json (libraries for that too)

reinterpret_cast binary data to an object is just wrong in C++ (constructors will not be called) and is undefined behavior. On top of that, if a string is a bit long then std::string will store its data at a totally different address (different from the string) and you will save incomplete data... so no this is not going to work

The suggested duplicate is about strings, but you have an object containing strings so the same issues apply.
